# SQL Max Recursion Error (100) with 2 employees in DB reporting to each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion

I see a lot of posts regarding this topic but I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem. The recursive query I'm using has worked excellent for almost all of my Managers, however, in 1 case I just came across, 2 managers are set to report to one another in the database, so when it goes into recursion, it errors out saying:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @pManagerName VARCHAR(50) = 'TIM'

; WITH CTE (EMP_ID, [USER_NAME], MGR_ID) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        EMP_ID, [USER_NAME], MGR_ID 
    FROM 
        [table]
    WHERE  
        [USER_NAME] = @pManagerName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        e.EMP_ID, e.[USER_NAME], e.MGR_ID
    FROM 
        CTE s 
    JOIN 
        [table] e ON s.EMP_ID = e.MGR_ID  -- This the infin loop bc 2 managers report to each other?
)
SELECT DISTINCT(EMP_ID) 
FROM CTE
WHERE [USER_NAME] <> @pManagerName
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)
```

Table looks like this:

```
EMP_ID  USER_NAME   MGR_ID
---------------------------------
  6     TIM             23   <-- Looks like TIM and SARA are the issue
 23     SARA             6   <--
 40     BRIAN           23
 77     LIZ              6
 94     PHIL            23
 95     JOHN            23
 100    Child Liz       77
 105    child child liz 100
```

So for the example above, when I run for @pManagerName = "TIM" (who is EMP_ID = 6), I want to get back everyone that reports to him, and under them as well, so:

```
 23
 77
 100
 105
```

Is there an easy way to avoid this that I'm not thinking of? Huge thanks in advance

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: Hi Gordon!  In the results above I'd like to see all of the EMP_IDs that report to "TIM" and under those reportees as well, which I didn't give in the data maybe I will udpate to make more clear.  I'm really just looking for a way for the recursive join loop to pick up Sara under Tim once, but not keep looping around until it errors out.  I assume "ON s.EMP_ID = e.MGR_ID" is the culprit and needs an additional condition or something?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just updated the question to be more specific, let me know if that clarifies thank you so much!!

Comment: This actually looks like a data issue rather than a query issue.  Is the scenario reflected in the data where two managers report to each-other actually occurring in the real world?

Comment: Yes in this case, because apparently they approve each others time.  I didn't make the decision to do that, I'm just a worker bee :(

Comment: So you don't want SARA's employees even though there's a line from them to TIM through her? But you do want SARA listed?

Comment: Assuming there can only be single-level-deep recursions (e.g. not some loop like 1->2->1 or 1->2->3->4->1), why not just add a line to the recursion like `and s.MGR_ID != e.EMP_ID`? If there can be recursions at any level, then it will require a more complicated solution though...

Comment: Is this perhaps an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? I suggest adding an extra status/role of `approves time` to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously need loop detection. SQL Server CTE doesn't have one built-in, but with some string-based tricks you can get away with it.

Look at this:

```
DECLARE @pManagerName varchar(50) = 'TIM'

;With CTE (EMP_ID, [USER_NAME], MGR_ID, PATH_IDS)
AS (
    SELECT EMP_ID, [USER_NAME], MGR_ID, PATH_IDS = '|' + CAST(EMP_ID AS nvarchar(max)) FROM [table]
    WHERE  [USER_NAME] = @pManagerName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e.EMP_ID, e.[USER_NAME], e.MGR_ID, PATH_IDS = PATH_IDS + '|' + CAST(e.EMP_ID AS nvarchar(max))
    FROM CTE s 
    JOIN [table] e 
        ON s.EMP_ID = e.MGR_ID  -- This the infin loop bc 2 managers report to each other?
    WHERE CHARINDEX('|' + CAST(e.EMP_ID AS nvarchar(max)) + '|', PATH_IDS, 0) = 0
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

What this does is convey the path information along the recursive CTE call. Path is just a string of identifiers separated by a pipe (you can change that).
This means that the root will have path fixed to its EMP_ID. Every node below will add the EMP_ID on its own.

E.g. there will be a node with path "6|23|40" (EMP_ID 40, BRIAN), because manager of 40 is 23, manager of 23 is 6, and manager of 6 is... well, we have to stop here to avoid the loop. The part `WHERE CHARINDEX(CAST(e.EMP_ID AS nvarchar(max)) + '|', PATH_IDS, 0) = 0` takes care of that.

Actually this is a prototype, and for a large number of nodes this could be slow, so the loop detection would have to be improved. But I hope you get the idea.

HTH

Comment: This idea is OK, but there are issues with the way it is executed. Probably should begin and end the `PATH_IDS` with '|' and then search for an ID encased in '|'+ID+'|', to avoid conflicts of say employeeID 1 being matched to employeeID '21|'

Comment: True that; as I said, this was a prototype and the issue is now corrected in the answer

Comment: This worked great thank you so much @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric !!  I would not have gotten this on my own and I appreciate you explaining how and what exactly this is doing to acheive the solution!